Distinction of concepts איש ,בעל, and אדון
When referring to the modern Hebrew word for husband, we usually use בעל. However, Sarah in Bereshis 18:12 uses אדון. Also (thanks Double AA) Leah calls her husband איש. What is the difference between these concepts, and when do we refer to G-d as בעל, when אדון, and when איש?

See Hoshea 2:18 and commentaries

We do say מי כמוך בעל גבורות addressing ה׳ in the amidah

Leah calls her husband Ish עַתָּה הַפַּעַם יִלָּוֶה אִישִׁי אֵלַי (and a few more times כִּי עַתָּה יֶאֱהָבַנִי אִישִׁי, הַמְעַט קַחְתֵּךְ אֶת-אִישִׁי, יִזְבְּלֵנִי אִישִׁי, אֲשֶׁר-נָתַתִּי שִׁפְחָתִי לְאִישִׁי)

What about Ribon? as in Ribbono Shel Olam (Master of the World)

@ClintEastwood that's a different question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110911/difference-between-%d7%a8%d7%91%d7%95%d7%9f-and-%d7%90%d7%93%d7%95%d7%9f/144137#144137

Do we ever refer to God as איש?

@DoubleAA Shemos 15:3 יְהוָ֖ה אִ֣ישׁ מִלְחָמָ֑ה יְהוָ֖ה שְׁמֹֽו׃

@YDJ that doesn't mean husband but warrior. Like איש האדמה means farmer. It's idiomatic. The literal English "man of war" or "man of the ground" misses the tone.

@DoubleAA then as Sholom suggested Hoshea 2:18 וְהָיָ֤ה בַיּוֹם־הַהוּא֙ נְאֻם־יְהֹוָ֔ה תִּקְרְאִ֖י אִישִׁ֑י וְלֹא־תִקְרְאִי־לִ֥י ע֖וֹד בַּעְלִֽי׃

Well, calling Hashem בעל would run into the obvious issue of that also being used as a name for an idolatrous deity.
Anyway, Malbim (Yeshayah 26:13) explains:

בעל מורה על הקנין שי"ל בגוף הדבר ולכן בא גם על דברים שאין בהם רוח חיים ובעל השור נקי, לא כן שם אדון, שעקרו על האדנות והגדולה
בעל refers to the ownership one has over the object, so it can be used even of inanimate objects, as in "the בעל of the ox is exempt."* Whereas אדון primarily means lordship and greatness.

* צע"ק that he first says "inanimate objects" and then brings an example with an ox. Perhaps he meant to say "animate but non-human objects."

It can be inanimate. The author of a sefer is also called בעל. Also in Shemone Esrei we call Hashem בעל גבורת.

@YDJ True. So maybe the Malbim meant to say just that: it can be used of any objects, animate or not.

Can one say that בעל due to physical ownership prevents one from having freedom of choice, but אדון grants his servants such a freedom?

@YDJ Could be, and maybe that would even explain why the worshippers of Baal called it that - pagan religions tended to view people as the helpless playthings of their gods. Interesting point; yasher koach.

El is also used to refer to gods and Adonai = Adonis but these idolatrous uses of the words don't prevent us from using them to describe god. Shadai is also like Sheid(im)

@ClintEastwood the question was not about all names of G-d, but about the names that express the concept of husband.

@ClintEastwood As for Adonis, anyway, the earliest attested uses of it far postdate most of Tanach.

Thanks to Sholom, we can also use Malbim on Hoshea 2:18:

והיה ביום ההוא נאום ה' תקראי אישי, שם בעל מורה על הממשלה והקנין שמושל על הדבר מפני שהוא שלו וקנינו, ושם איש מורה על האהבה והקורבה והאישות, ועד עתה שלא היה לה' קורבה עמהם, והשגחתו היתה נסתרת ומעוטפת במסך טבעי היו עובדים מצד היראה וקוראים לו בעלי מצד ממשלתו עליהם, שבזה יביטו לפעמים אל משרתיו אשר הם אמצעיים אל השפע המגיע להם מאתו על ידם וייראו ויכבדו גם אותם, אבל לעתיד יתהלך בתוכם ויתן להם ברכותיו מבלי אמצעי כאשר יתיחד איש עם אשתו, כמ"ש חז"ל ע"ז שתהיה ככלה בבית חמיה ולא ככלה בית אביה, כי יהיה מעונתו בעולם השפל לשכון כבוד בתוכם, ותקבל שפע האלהית פנים אל פנים, ותעבוד מאהבה ולא תירא ותכבד זולתו:
And in that day — declares  G-D — You will call [Me] Ishi, and no more will you call Me Baali.  The name בעל is refers to one's rulership and ownership, i.e. one rules over a thing (or person) because it (he/she) is his and acquired. The name איש refers to love and closeness of relation. Until this point, for Hashem there was no closeness with them, and His providence was hidden and wrapped in a natural veil. They worshiped Him out of fear and called Him בעלי because of His rule over them, so that in this way they would sometimes look at His servants (i.e. angels, etc.) who are intermediaries, through which people receive His abundance (שפע), and they would fear and honor these intermediaries as well. But in the future, He will walk among them and give them His blessings without intermediaries just like a man unites with his wife. As the Sages say, (Pesachim 87a) "Rabbi Yoḥanan said: She shall be like a bride in her father-in-law’s house, where she experiences a close relationship with her husband. And she shall not be like a bride still in the betrothal period and living in her father’s house, during which time her relationship with her husband has still not developed." It will be His time in the lowly world to dwell in honor among them, and she will receive the abundance of G-d face to face, and she will worship out of love, and neither fear nor honor anyone else.

Thus we see that בעל due to physical ownership prevents one from having freedom of choice, but אדון or איש grants his servants such a freedom.
